# Why doesn't the Java compiler download imported packages?

Tags: java, package, javac

I'm trying to run a Lucene Java application on my local machine. I get this compilation error:

```
package org.apache.commons.digester does not exist
```

because of

```
import org.apache.commons.digester.Digester;
```

Isn't the compiler downloading the package from the Internet?
If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the compiler doesn't download packages from the Internet. Some build management tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) do it if you configure them properly and add the package to the project dependencies. But without such a tool you should download the jar manually and put it on the compiler classpath.

Comment: Uhm ok. I've actually downloaded Apache Lucene and I want to run an app with it. Do I realy need to add a management tool like Maven ? i've a build.xml and lucene-core-3.0.3.jar in my folder

Comment: @Patrick, if you already have Lucene, your project is small and you do not foresee too many new dependencies in the future, you can get by without Maven. Just make sure the Lucene jar is accessible for both the compiler upon compiling, and the JVM (classpath) upon running your app.

Comment: @Patrick: You need to download Digester anyway since that's not included in Lucene, but just a dependency.

Comment: @BalusC ok, I've downloaded Digester. Now, how can I make it accessible to the compiler. This is what I'm doing now but I get the same error: javac -cp commons-digester-2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar myApp.java

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven you could download the lib by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
```

Else you have to download it [here](http://commons.apache.org/digester). Then just add the .jar to your Buildpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *maven* and added this as dependency then it will download it for you. otherwise

You can download it from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/) , appropriate version. and add it to your app's class path

Answer (score 0):

No the compiler does not download packages from the internet when you import them. **The [naming convention for packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) makes them appear like URLs but they are not** and the compiler certainly makes no attempt to download dependencies.

The idea is that if all creators of Java libraries conform to this convention and use their domain name in package names then class name clashes between libraries from different authors can be avoided. However as previously stated this just a naming convention and has relationship to dependency management.

**Some build tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) have sophisticated and relatively easy to use [dependency management mechanisms.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) The popular [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build tool also has this capability through the [Ivy dependency manager.](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)**